# Change the Target Framework version  from 4 to 3.5 for a Unit Test C#

Tags: 2010

When I attempt to change the Target Framework version  from 4 to 3.5 for a Unit Test C# project by following the description in this article
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483939/unable-to-change-target-framework-version-on-unit-test-projects?wa=wsignin1.0

1. Unload the test project
2. Edit the xxxx.csproj
3. Remove {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}; from ProjectTypeGuids
4. Change the TargetFrameworkVersion to v3.5 (Save)
5. Reload the project
6. Change the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll as specified in the other workaround.

I am not able to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll v9.0.

VS2010 SP1 shall solve this problem.

Anyone who are running VS2010 UnitTest without VS2010 SP1?

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like MSTest is not an option until VS2010 SP1.

For the time being I use NUnit (projekt must be targeting framework 3.5) and TestDriven.net, and that works just fine.